# Good introduction to metaprogramming in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, meta-programming

I would like to make for example imperative programs as output of Prolog (shaders of graphic card) and also event-driven programs (game logic) ... also I would like to learn how to metaprogram in Prolog in general.

I believe there might be some insights or advices how to do it; I don't want to jump into it not prepared and hack until I make working programs.

I wonder what is good introduction to metaprogramming in Prolog? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a specific use case in mind?

Comment: +1 for helpful question. It is slightly complicated. I am not sure if I should split question. I am interested in metaprogramming in Prolog in general and I have some specific cases too (I am not working at them yet). In this question I am interested just in introduction.

Answer (score 2):

There are online tutorials (do a web search for "programming prolog") that are OK. It all depends on how you like to learn: online tutorials, books, or experimentation?  It sounds like you're considering a large project using Prolog, so I'd recommend one of the books that covers large application development in Prolog (like the Art of Prolog).